# Most Efficient Way to Sort By String, Based on Defined Array in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, performance, sorting

I am trying to find the most efficient way to sort an array based on a defined order from another array and display it in my presenter. There is a property of the array that needs sorting, that I want to sort on, 'name'.  So there is a function, 'dogs_available' that returns a collection of objects that looks like:

```
[{name:'Timmy', size:'small', eyes:'brown'},{name:'Rico', size:'large', eyes:'purple'}]
```

So I want

```
sort_order = ['Timmy', 'Charlie', 'Rico', 'Hannah']
m.dogs_available.sort do |x,y|
  x = sort_order.index x.name
  y = sort_order.index y.name
  if x.nil?
    -1
  elsif y.nil?
    -1
  else
    x <=> y
  end
end
```

And then to print it out (just for testing, I'll clean it up later) it looks like:

```
dogs = m.dogs_available
text = ""
dogs.each do |dog|
  text += "<h4>#{dog.name}</h4>"
end
text.html_safe
```

For starters, this sort doesn't work. Also, I am confident this isn't the best way to sort/compare.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing sort logic can be replaced with

```
m.dogs_available.sort_by{|hash| sort_order.index(hash[:name]) || -1}
```

however, where is dogs_available coming from?  Usually in rails you'd be pulling data out of the database, and you can do your sorting then.

Comment: The data is coming from an API on a 3rd party. Your solution works, however the order is a bit strange that if a dogs name isn't in the list, it will appear first in the list if being compared against -1, so I could make it a large indices to work.

Comment: The sorting algorithm assigns -1 to anything not in the list (like in your code) which will put it to the start of the array since it will be compared against the index of the other names (which will be 0, 1, 2, etc).  If you want things not in the array to appear at the end you could set the default to 10000 or something, instead of -1.